# Is there a pain independent of physical nerve interactions?

Tags: pain-and-pleasure

What is the absolute nature of pain? Is there such thing as a pain independent of physical happenings in the body?

Comment: How do you define "pain"?

Comment: @Niel: As this questions evolved from this other q:http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/9739/do-all-forms-of-death-result-in-some-form-of-pain, I take your comment to be just a restatement of the question. Can pain be defined as just physical stuffs, or are there other things involved, and according to whom?

Comment: @Lukas: maybe my analytical roots are showing, but I think an added emphasis on the search for what the word can/should be fit to, adds more meaning to  the question (or clarifies its intent perhaps). Not that it will necessarily be more answerable, for that.

Comment: Maybe a bit good will would solve all that. Physicalists will tell you that you cannot, since there is just the physical, dualists will maybe tell you something about soul-pain, where nothing physical is involved, and then there are those who say that there is some non-physical involved, and i think they are called 'property-dualists', or something like that.

Comment: I take the question to be a reference request for different positions in the philosophy of mind that deal with pain, or have results that include pain(because it is a mental state).

Comment: Yes, pain is independent. First question is on you.

Comment: Are you aware of phantom pain? This is when you have a limb amputated yet still feel pain in that limb. It's very common. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_pain

Comment: We must not confuse pain with sufferring: Cassell defines pain not only as a sensation, but also “as an experience embedded in beliefs about causes and diseases and their consequences”, and suffering as “the state of severe distress associated with events that threaten the intactness of person”.Both pain and suffering are considered to have physical and psychological dimensions, and in this sense, it is true that Cassell avoids the classical association between pain and body, suffering and mind.Cassel EJ. The Nature of Suffering and the Goals of Medicine. Oxford: Oxford University Press; 2004.

Comment: Pain is a phenomenon which includes both nociception –“the mechanism involved in receiving painful stimuli”–and the subsequent attachment of meaning to such sensation. He recognizes the universality of nociception (“certain kinds of stimuli elicit the sensory response of nociception in every culture, now and forever”), but does not consider pain to be the same as nociception; for him, pain includes the meaning which the subjects ascribe to nociception, and such meaning changes from culture to culture, from person to person.

Comment: See https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28958214/#:~:text=Suffering%20is%20proposed%20to%20be,and%20suffering%20are%20considered%20unpleasant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analysis of [phantom limb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_limb) syndrome suggests that pain (along with many types of sensations) can occur in a place other than where they *seem* to be happening, but there's no evidence it's not physical in nature. That is, the experience of pain may be "all in your mind" but still the result of physical processes.

More info:

http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/31555.Phantoms_in_the_Brain

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilayanur_S._Ramachandran

Comment: If its at the end "all in your mind" then it can be also result of the mind itself. And not that thing which you called "physical", which itself can be in the _bigger_ mind.

Comment: @AsphirDom - I'm inclined to think minds result from physical processes but I'm not making that argument here. That argument is well explored in other places. I am suggesting that minds _might_ be physical, and if one accepts that minds are physical than it follows that pain is too.

Comment: Good point, but isn't it obvious that Physical _IS_ mind?

Comment: @AsphirDom I think minds are a physical process, but I'm just not prepared to argue that point.  There are better people than me for that.